# Show only preview of posts on the homepage?

Tags: plugins, homepage, previews

Is it possible to only have a couple lines shown per post (or even 0 lines) on the homepage? Instead of dumping the whole article on the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look somewhere after the "[Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)" starts (it starts with `<?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>`) in your `index.php` file.

Find `<?php the_content(); ?>` and change it to `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`.  If you don't want any content, just remove `the_content()` all together.

If you're using a theme from wordpress.org, it would best to do this in a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), so you can keep the original theme up to date.

Answer (score 0):

lines of text? that would be `<?php the_excerpt() ?>`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know about it then my suggestion is to not use theme editor from wordpress because one single syntax error may harm your site

so login to your hosting panel

public_html -> your wordpress folder -> wp_content -> themes -> your theme name -> child theme name (if any) -> index.php

Now open it in your text editor and find the_content(); and replace it with the_excerpt();

and then go to your site and press cntrl + f5 if its not changed yet and you're done.